# Chrome/Webkit inline-block refresh problem

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit, css

The problem I found is the following:

**Situation**: I have overall div that has a `inline-block` display. Inside it are two element that have an `inline-block` display as well.

Then I add (thanks to JavaScript) a `<br/>` between the two elements. The second goes to the next line, which is the normal behavior.

**Buggy part**: The `<br/>` is then removed (JavaScript again) and... the display doesn't change. It appears that the box of the overall div is not recalculated. In the end I have two similar markup that doesn't appear the same way (which is a bit problematic, isn't it).

It works fine on Firefox (it appears to be webkit based as the Android browser behave the same way). So my question is, is there a workaround that doesn't use methods that will alter the DOM? The library used is jQuery.

A test case [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4yj7U/1/).

**EDIT:** As suggested by duri, I filled a bug report in webkit bugzilla, it's [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=67472). But I'm still looking for a workaround `;)`

Comment: Interesting. Replacing the `div` completely does work - http://jsfiddle.net/4yj7U/2/. I'm curious to know what's the reason behind this behaviour.

Comment: Changing CSS `style.display` for _div#ahah_ from `inline-block` to `inline` workarounds this bug for Chrome. It's important for you to have `inline-block` display value for _div#ahah_?

Comment: Please consider filling a bug in Webkit's bugzilla.

Comment: @Andrew: yes, it's needed for the layout I use (it's way more complex than the test case ;) )

Comment: This is a fix that only works the first time: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/4yj7U/7/

Comment: I need a fix that will work every time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Way what I found: remove all childs from overall DIV, and then append all except BR's:

```
function removeBr(){
    var ahah=document.getElementById("ahah");
    var childs=[],child;
    while(child=ahah.firstChild) {
        if(!child.tagName||child.tagName.toLowerCase()!=='br')
            childs.push(child);
        ahah.removeChild(child);
    }
    for(var i=0;i<childs.length;i++)
        ahah.appendChild(childs[i]);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4yj7U/4/

Other variant:

```
function removeBr(){
    var node=$("#ahah")[0];
    node.style.display='inline';
    $("#ahah").children("br").remove(); 
    setTimeout(function(){node.style.display='';},0);
}
```

Comment: I had that one as well, it uses to much DOM appending/removal for me.

Comment: This can create _flashing_ of page content when `style.display` is changed to `inline` and then back to `inline-block`

Comment: Yeah but this is a minor disadvantage. I need this change when the screen orientation changes (on a phone/tablet computer), so the user probably won't notice.

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, you could set the style to `display: block` when you want them on individual lines and revert to `inline-block` when you want them to be friends.

I have created a [JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Sohnee/qJXh7/)

Which demonstrates this fix:

```
function addBr(){
    $('span').css({ display: 'block'});
}
function removeBr(){
    $('span').css({ display: 'inline-block'});
}

$("#add").click(addBr);
$("#remove").click(removeBr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug still exists, so here's another workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/4yj7U/19/

```
$("span").css('display', 'none');

setTimeout(function(){
    $('span').css('display', 'inline-block');
}, 0);
```

This makes Chrome re-render the spans and displays them properly.